# How to decide whether 2 MSI with different product code belong to same product or different?

Tags: windows-installer, packaging

I have 2 MSIs of an Outlook Add-in, one for Outlook 2007 and another for Outlook 2003. If I install the add-in MSI for Outlook 2007 on a machine having Outlook 2007 and if there is already another version installed of the same add-in, that gets uninstalled if that is a lower version and if higher, then the installation of MSI fails.same is the behavior for machine having Outlook 2003.
But if Outlook 2003 machine , having add-in installed, gets upgraded to outlook 2007 and then If I install add-in for 2007,that result in dual installation i.e. neither previous version gets uninstalled nor new installation fails and the new version also gets installed.I can varify that from Add/Remove Programs
How it is decided that different version of an MSI (having different product code) belong to same product or different so that it uninstalls or fails the installation depending on the version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSI uses the [UpgradeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to decide whether two packages with a different ProductCode belong to the same product.